# What is $\gcd(12345,54321)$?

Tags: number-theory

> What is $\gcd(12345,54321)$?

I noticed that after trying $\gcd(12,21),\gcd(123,321),$ and $\gcd(1234,4321)$ that they are all less then or equal to $3$. That leads me to question if there is an easy way to calculate such greatest common divisors.

Comment: $12345678$ and the same thing written backwards are both divisible by $9$. One "easy" way to calculate is the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would the best way be to just find the prime factorizations? I was thinking there would be a nice trick since they written backwards of each other.

Comment: Prime factorization seems to be hard in general. The gcd is much easier.

Comment: @user19405892 We don't necessarily need the prime factorizations to find the GCD because we can use [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which will be much easier since both numbers can be expressed as a summation, but finding the prime factorizations of summations is hard while the Euclidean algorithm can work with summations much more easily.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Still I think it is an interesting property that once we factor out either $3$ or $9$ the remaining parts are relatively prime. That's why I was wondering about a "nice trick".

Comment: What's easy to prove for the sum of the digits is that $3$ divides both of these numbers for $12,123,12345,123456$ and that $9$ divides both of these numbers for $12345678,123456789$. What's hard to show, however, is that **there are no other common divisors**, but according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(123456789,987654321)), that seems to be the case.

Comment: Wait, I just realized that $$12+21=33$$ $$123+321=444$$ $$1234+4321=5555$$ $$[...]$$ $$12345678+87654321=99999999$$ $$123456789+987654321=1111111110$$ Maybe this pattern along with the Euclidean algorithm will help us?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the sum of the digits of $12345$ and $54321$ , it's divisible by $3$. So $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

When $54321$ is divided by $12345$, the quotient is $4$ and the remainder is $4941$:
$$
54321 = (4\times12345) + 4941.
$$
Therefore (as Euclid taught us),
$$
\gcd(12345,54321) = \gcd(12345,4941).
$$
When $12345$ is divided by $4941$, the quotient is $2$ and the remainder is $2463$:
$$
12345 = (2\times4941) + 2463.
$$
Therefore
$$
\gcd(12345,4941) = \gcd(2463,4941).
$$
And so on.  Keep going until you're done.  (The numbers keep getting smaller, so it can't go on forever.)  And you'll find in this case it doesn't take much longer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generalize this cleanly to values greater than $9$ digits, we should probably think of $54321$ as $\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot 10^{k-1}$ for $n=5$, so when $n=11$ we get $120987654321$ instead of, say, $110987654321$.

Similarly for $12345$ can be generalized to $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (n-k+1) \cdot 10^{k-1}$.  When $n=11$ this is $12345679011$, not $1234567891011$: we trade off the idea of "writing it backwards" for a lot greater algebraic simplicity.

The closed forms of these two sums are $\frac1{81} (9n\cdot 10^n - 10^n + 1)$ and $\frac1{81} (10^{n+1} - 9n - 10)$, respectively.  So if we denote their GCD by $g$, then:

$$81g = (9n\cdot 10^n - 10^n + 1, 10^{n+1} - 9n - 10).$$

Let's try to bound this.  The left term is not divisible by $10$: if we multiply it by $10$, then the gcd will increase by a factor of $(n,10)$, so

$$(n,10)\cdot81g = (9n\cdot 10^{n+1} - 10^{n+1} + 10, 10^{n+1} - 9n - 10) \\
= (9n\cdot 10^{n+1} - 10^{n+1} + 10 - (9n-1)\cdot(10^{n+1} - 9n - 10), 10^{n+1} - 9n - 10) \\
= (81n^2 + 81n, 10^{n+1} - 9n - 10).$$

So in particular $g \le n(n+1)/(n,10)$, which is reasonably small compared to the sizes of numbers here.  Nevertheless, it does get much larger than $3$ or $9$ in practice: for $n=44$ it's as high as $99$, and for $n=110$ it's $1221$, just meeting the upper bound!

I think you might be able to reduce the GCD expression further using binomial expansion on $(1+9)^{n+1}$, but it gets kind of hairy.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcrcrl}
54324 & = & 4\times 12345 & + & 4944 &
\\
12345 & = & 2\times 4944 & + & 2457 &
\\
4944 & = & 2\times 2457 & + & 30&
\\
2457 & = & 81\times 30 & + & 27&
\\
30 & = & 1\times 27 & + & \color{#f00}{\large 3} & \color{#f00}{\large\Leftarrow}
\\
27 & = & 9\times 3 & + & 0 &
\end{array}\right.
$$